# iOS Wrong Image Size when using my own image suffix

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, retina-display

I use bg.png for iPhone, bg@2x for both iPhone retina and iPad, bg@4x for iPad retina. 
Here is the code i wrote: (in Helper.m)

```
+ (UIImage *) imageNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    name = [name stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@""];
    UIImage *image;
    if (IS_IPAD) {
        if (IS_RETINA) {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@4x.png", name]];
            if (image) {
                return image;
            }
        }

        return [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x.png", name]];
    }
    else {
        if (IS_RETINA) {
            image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x.png", name]];
            if (image) {
                return image;
            }
        }
        return [UIImage imageNamed:name];
    }
}
```

The file is correct, but the size of image is wrong.

If the file is automatically picked by the system (use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]`), then on iPhone retina, the size is still 320x480 (1 point = 4 pixels).

but if i use `[Helper imageNamed:@"bg.png"]`, the size is 640x960. (1 point = 1 pixel)

So anyway to correct the size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a retina device

```
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]
```

searches for `bg@2x.png` first. If that image exists, it is loaded and the `scale` property 
of the image is automatically set to `2.0`. On the other hand,

```
 [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg@2x.png"]
```

also loads that image, but uses the default `scale = 1.0`.

***If*** you have to use a custom loading mechanism, you have to adjust the scale factor.
Since `scale` is a read-only property of `UIImage` it cannot be set directly. One method
I know of is

```
UIImage *tmpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg@2x.png"];
UIImage *properlyScaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[tmpImage CGImage]
                                           scale:2.0
                                     orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Comment: works like a charm. thanks. (i was trying    [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) scale:2];
but cgimage one is much faster

Comment: @OMGPOP: `imageWithData:scale:` (as suggested by rmaddy) should work as well, but you should call it with the image data from disk (`NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:...]`) directly. - Loading an `UIImage` first and converting it back to `NSData` is of course slower.

Comment: At least with iOS9 and Xcode 7.3, both imageNamed:"bg" and imageNamed:"bg@2x.png" both have scale set to 2 (and I assume both are finding the @2x.

Answer (score 5):

Why reinvent what Apple already provides? The `imageNamed:` method already supports the ability to load iPhone or iPad specific images by using the `~iphone` and `~ipad` suffixes.

To get an iPad specific retina image you just name it `bg@2x~ipad.png`.
To get an iPad specific non-retina image you name it `bg~ipad.png`.

The problem you have with your code is due to the non-standard naming conventions, the image is loaded with the wrong scale.

**Update**: based on additional information in the comments, a better approach to solve this issue is to replace the use of the `UIImage imageNamed:` method with calls to the `UIImage imageWithData:scale:` method. This provides better memory management as well as the ability to specify the proper scale for the custom naming conventions and image sharing between iPhone retina and iPad non-retina.

Comment: because I use the same image for iPhone retina and iPad. and I ignore some large background image for ipad retina. you should post it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: But what happens down the road when a new iOS device has a double-retina screen and images actually start using the `@4x` suffix for this? Your custom naming convention is a bad idea. It also makes no sense to share iPhone retina and non-retina iPad images. Since you are using `imageNamed:` (which caches images) these must be for small images used for icons, right? So it makes no sense to share non-retina and retina images. If these are full screen sized images then you should not be using `imageNamed:` due to the caching.

Comment: I have 400+ photoshop'ed photos which are 400x400 (which take 40M out of 50M), I don't think I can duplicate and rename all the 400 photos. This answer is not constructive.

Comment: Given the additional information that these are larger images (not icons) then you should pay attention to what I said about not using `imageNamed:`. You will run out of memory quicker. To solve your issue and to get better memory management, use the `imageWithData:scale:` method to load the images. This way you can specify the desired image scale.

Comment: the scale seems to be a readonly property. let me try the data. thanks

Comment: @rmaddy: I did not see your update while writing an answer, your solution is very similar to my suggestion.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the imageWithData:scale: is a bit slow. (even just 2 photos) cgimage one is faster.

Comment: Just keep in mind that the other answer is still using `imageNamed:` which may lead to memory issues due to the size of these images.

Comment: @rmaddy can u explain more about it? I used to use non-arc and images are successfully deallocated.

Comment: No, -imageNamed does not cause memory issues anymore. This was once in  very early iOS version and since then this rumor stayed alive. I think Apple mentioned at a WWDC session the problem is long gone. -imageNamed: uses NSCache and other very clever mechanisms. When you create an image with this it loads the data first time when you really need it (for example UIImageView).